# Sencha Touch list scrolling while soft keyboard is up

Tags: html, ios, sencha-touch, mobile-safari

I'm building a mobile app that lives inside of a UIWebView and is written in sencha.

Right now, I have a page that has a ext.list containing `<textarea>` element inside of the rows.

When the user clicks on the text area, the soft keyboard comes up and pushes the screen as expected. However, if you try to scroll the list while the keyboard is up, the list will dart all the way down to the bottom. At this point, you can try to scroll the list back up to see the `<textarea>`  (keyboard still up), but whenever you're done scrolling and remove your finger it will immediately stick you down at the bottom of the list again.

Once you dismiss the soft keyboard, the problem goes away. We want scrolling with the keyboard up, unfortunately.

Things I've tried:
*Use the `scrollstart` event to unfocus the `<textarea>` and dismiss the keyboard when scrolling begins **works, but like I said, we want scrolling with the keyboard up**

*Put the `<textarea>` on a toolbar, or just plain fix it to the middle of the screen. It doesn't seem to care where the `<textarea>` is. The main problem seems to be the keyboard + scrolling interactions.

I've looked around for some time now and cannot find *anything* on this. It seems most people are complaining about Android, which I haven't even explored yet. I feel like this has got to be something people are incorporating into their apps, though (like a search that displays results while you type and you can browse those results), so I must just be missing something? Does Sencha 2 fix this?

Thanks in advance. I can post code and/or a demo as per request.